# Redirecting non www to https://www not working apache2 config

Tags: url, redirect, apache2, lets-encrypt, no-www

Sometimes when I write host.com in the browser, it redirects me to https://www.example.com
but when reloading https://example.com it doesn't redirect.

I have tried many methods none of them worked for me.

Steps that I followed are:

1. nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf
2. Added one of them at once to the file so the file structure looks like this:

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.

RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

3. removed old sites-enabled/example.com.conf
4. a2ensite example.com.conf
5. service apache2 reload

NOTE: I've tried many RewriteCond but step 2 worked for me. But the problem is in some browser security warning
prompts while browsing https://example.com, even I've SSL certificate for both example.com and www.example.com

Maybe it's due to SSL certificate installation or whatever I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Added the same lines in .htaccess file solved my problem:

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.

RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]